# Bitbake: How to build a specific python3 recipe

Tags: python, linux, yocto

I'm currently attempting to build a custom Linux image that include python3 (version 3.4) but encountered some build error during the attempt,i usually use a top layer i've created to add newer versions of packages or add recipies that doesn't exist in pocky or openembedded layers since i'm using yocto daisy which most of its packages are deprecated.

I've successfully build my image with python2.7 and python3.3 which are already available in the pocky meta layers by:

- Adding **IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " python3 python3-misc python3-modules"** to conf/local.conf
- Applying this [patch](https://git.congatec.com/yocto/poky/commit/b5e9dbbe8245f47d2d3d77f219a2d30a48e1918b) to avoid conflict with 2to3 symlink from Python 2:

However, when i try to build the project with python3.4 after adding the recipe from [the OpenEmbedded Layer Index](http://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/recipes/?q=python3) and setting the preferred version using:

```
PREFERRED_VERSION_python3 = "3.4.1"
```

i get this compilation error:

```
 * satisfy_dependencies_for: Cannot satisfy the following dependencies for python3-modules:
 *  python3-elementtree *   python3-mmap *  python3-fcntl *     python3-gdbm *  python3-fcntl *     python3-resource *  python3-mmap *  python3-elementtree *   python3-syslog * 
 * opkg_install_cmd: Cannot install package python3-modules.
```

Any insights?